# Grid.Mvc missing documentation

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Looking to implement Grid.Mvc in my MVC5 application however the documentation links on the project web site - http://gridmvc.codeplex.com/ dont appear to be working...be looking online and cant seem to find any reference to it.

There are some wiki links on https://github.com/leniel/Grid.Mvc/wiki however they do not seem to be complete...

Anyone manage to find a copy?

cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That version looks to be very old and no longer maintained.

Why not use a newer type of MVC Grid. We use [this one](https://github.com/NonFactors/MVC6.Grid)

The documentation is available [here](http://mvc6-grid.azurewebsites.net/)

Comment: Thanks for this i will take a look (sorry for the late reply)

Comment: MVC6.grid seems a fair option however i am going with grid.mvc despite the lack of documentation.

Comment: @bsod_ why would you rather Grid.MVC vs MVC6.grid?

Comment: There are many of us who already have Grid.Mvc installed and love it - it does all the basics really well and we just need a copy of the documentation.

Comment: VincentW, I have been looking for documentation of Grid.Mvc, want to learn about Encode and Sanitize, kindly help.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to that archived CodePlex site, you can download the project archive, and there is a `wiki/Render` folder containing all the html pages with documentation.

Here's the link to the CodePlex site: https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=gridmvc

And the direct link to the archive download: https://codeplexarchive.blob.core.windows.net/archive/projects/gridmvc/gridmvc.zip

Answer (score 0):

I've found this link:
https://archive.org/details/sylirana_ms_codeplex_zips

You have to go to the TARS folder and you'll find the right link into mscodeplex-g-3.tar or, for short:
https://archive.org/download/sylirana_ms_codeplex_zips/tars/mscodeplex-g-3.tar/.%2Fgridmvc.zip
Bye